# IF-ELSE statement not recognizing second IF condition

Tags: google-sheets

As an avid player of Team Fortress 2, I decided to start a small side-project where I wanted to create a spreadsheet that would organize and keep current the values of various items on my wishlist of things to eventually buy in-game. However, I'm having a bit of trouble with the IF-ELSE statement to determine how prices are read off. You can see the spreadsheet for yourself [at this location](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1IaCff9JdhoaNxm4eU-rWCNi_MjkihIjmZPcfNP3S-ZI/edit?usp=sharing), and hopefully you can understand what I'm trying to do with it. Basically, what I want is this:

- If an item is priced at 'X Earbuds' items (*also known as 'buds'*), it would reference the individual price of a single 'Earbuds' item and multiply it by its cost in scrap metal (*the lowest available denomination in the TF2 economy*), which is then upscaled to larger denominations like 'reclaimed' or 'refined metal' easily.
- If an item is instead priced at 'Y Mann Co. Keys' (*or just 'keys'*), it would do the same thing as above, but referencing a different part of the sheet with a slightly shorter equation to determine the price.
- Otherwise, if it's priced in 'X Refined Metal' (*sometimes called 'refined' or just 'ref' in shorthand*) or not listed with a specific unit or denomination, it defaults to just dividing the number by 9 to get the amount of scrap metal the item costs.

Here's the problem I'm having with the statement, however, which is as follows:

```
=IF(SEARCH("bud", $C7), ROUND($B7*$F$5), IF(SEARCH("key", $C7), ROUND($B7*$F$4), ROUND($B7*9)))
```

What it **should** do is look for the phrase 'bud' in the currency window; if it can't find that, it should look for 'key' instead anywhere in the phrase; and if it can't find either of those, it defaults to thinking the price is listed as refined metal... except if finding the phrase 'bud' returns false, the whole statement throws back an error instead of trying to instead search for 'key'. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here and/or how to fix it so that it works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=if(regexmatch(C6, "(?i)bud"), ROUND($B6*$F$5), if(regexmatch(C6, "(?i)key"), ROUND($B6*$F$4), ROUND($B6*9)))
```

and drag further down. See if that works ?

Comment: It did indeed work, just as I intended. It works in all example cases in the spreadsheet... thank you kindly!